# Using custom names in a Spring Data JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a spring-boot-project and using a *JpaRepository* interface.
According to [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) one can write Custom Implementations.

Here is an example showing what I want to do.

I have a simple class *Client*:

```
@Entity
public class Client {
  @Id
  Long id;
  @Column
  String name;
  @Column
  Date since;

  // ... methods omitted 
}
```

, the *ClientRepository*:

```
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>, ClientRepositoryCustom {
  List<Client> findBySinceBetween(Date start, Date end);
}
```

, the *ClientRepositoryCustom*:

```
public interface ClientRepositoryCustom {
  List<Client> getClientsSinceYear(int year);
}
```

and finally the *ClientRepositoryImpl*:

```
@Repository
public class ClientRepositoryImpl implements ClientRepositoryCustom {
  @Overwrite
  List<Client> getClientsSinceYear(int year) {
    // ... implementation details
  }
}
```

I want to have a query like `getClientsSinceYear(int year)`.

I know I could write this query like this `findBySinceBetween(Date start, Date end)`, and pass the first and last day of the year in. But I want to pass only one parameter into the function.

Which level of freedom do I have in choosing a name?
Is this even possible?
Is there a trigger word, that I have to use if I want a name that has noting to do with the properties of my entity?

If I query e.g. for two properties. It **seems** I can write a method like `findByName(String name, int year)`, but I would rather not have a method with an additional parameter that is unrelated to the methods name.

Thanks in advance, any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a custom query with @Query

[Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

For Microsoft SQL Server you can write for example

```
@Query("select * from client_table where year(yourColumn) = ?1")
Client findClientCreatedInYear(int year);
```

You will find similar SQL queries for other dbms in the internet.

Comment: This seems to work. For this solution I don't need the *ClientRepositoryCustom*, which is okay. But if I want to "hide" the query details in the implementation, then there is no solution, or?

Comment: There are possibilities to put the named queries to orm.xml but i like the solution with @Query, it gives also some transparence to other developers. From what i've seen its best practice to put theses queries directly to the repository.